# Suppose that $|Z(R)| = 1$. Show that $|C_R(a)| \neq p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let p be a fixed prime. Let $R$  any ring of order $p^2$ with identity. Suppose that $|Z(R)| = 1$, where $Z(R) = \{z \in R; zr = rz, \forall r \in R\}$ and $C_R(a) = \{r \in R; ra = ar\}$. Show that $|C_R(a)| \neq p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something seems to be wrong here. The subring generated by the identity will have at least $p$ elements and is contained in the center $Z(R)$. Therefore the assumption $|Z(R)|=1$ cannot be satisfied.

Comment: The subring generated by identity is $R$. Why does it contain $Z(R)$?

Comment: $0,1 \in Z(R)$ then $|Z(R)|>1$

Comment: The subring generated by the identity may be a proper subring of $R$, for example if $R=\mathbb F_p[x]/(x^2)$. It is contained in $Z(R)$, because $1\in Z(R)$ and $Z(R)$ is a subring.